# Redirect in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a paginated display in which on each page call I set the current URI string into a session (in my controller).

```
$current = $this->uri->uri_string();
$this->session->set_userdata('return_to', $current);
```

From the view the user can click a link to go somewhere else (an edit form), which when submitted (and form validation is correct) I want to return to the correct page of the paginated results.

```
if($this->form_validation->run('edit') == TRUE )
{
    $back_to = NULL;
    $back_to = '/'.$this->session->userdata('return_to');
    ....
    redirect($back_to);
}
```

Seems to work sometimes in Firefox but dies in Chrome, redirect to favicon.ico

Any and all help appreciated

**UPDATE:**
My problem isn't due to relative/absolute addresses, for some weird reason in the second controller the redirect aims to favicon.ico, not what was stored in the session.

Comment: Perhaps `$back_to = site_url() . $this->session->userdata('return_to');`?

Comment: Having same problem it's been hours :( Have you find any solution?

Comment: Found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300311/codeigniter-weird-parameter-favicon-ico

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE )
{
    if($this->session->userdata('return_to')
    {
       redirect($this->session->userdata('return_to'));
    }
    else
    {
      redirect(base_url());
     // or trigger some error
    }
}
```

Don't need to assign a variable, `redirect()` uses both a full url and a segmented url (much like site_url(), which is exactly what is returned by `uri_string()`.

So if this doesn't work, it's likely your session is not set or expired. Also, consider that CI's sessions are *cookies* , so a browser can has its role in here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an absolute URL and not a relative one.

Try this

```
if($this->form_validation->run('edit') == TRUE )
{
    $back_to = NULL;
    $back_to = 'http://www.mydomain.com/'.$this->session->userdata('return_to');
    ....
    redirect($back_to);
}
```

As stealthyninja pointed out it's probably better to use CodeIgniter's site_url() or base_url() instead of hard coding it. Set the site_url() in the config.php (i believe)